# Django model where field is based on another field unless specified otherwise

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a django model called **Car** and another called **UserCar** which has a related car object.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mpg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)

class UserCar(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    mpg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

I would like to override the save function on **UserCar** such that *if no value for mpg is specified*, the model instance is pre-populated with the value of mpg on the related Car object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
class UserCar(models.Model):

    ... # your fields here


    # Override the save function here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.mpg is None:
            self.mpg = self.car.mpg
        super(UserCar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```